# Web.config in website root is interfering with additional application Web.config (IIS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis

I have 2 separate ASP.NET web applications setup in IIS that need to interact as one.

I created a New Website in IIS. I put the files for App1 in the root directory of the Website. I then created a directory called Admin and added App2 files. I right clicked the Admin directory in IIS and clicked Convert to Web Application.

It seems like the web.config in the root (App1) is interfering with the web.config within App2.

Is there a better way to set this up? Should both be their own applications within an empty Website? I kind of wanted to avoid this since I want the effect of www.mydomain.com for the main app and then www.mydomain.com/Admin for App2.

Comment: What sections are causing the issues? You could just create new empty sections in your /admin web.config to override those in the root?

Answer (score 0):

Your Admin website will inherit settings from parent (and therefore the root website) web.config.

You can explicitly override settings in the Admin web.config.

Also for configuration sections that have collections, you can often use `clear` to clear settings from the parent, e.g.:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <clear/>
  <add ... />
</connectionStrings>

<appSettings>
  <clear/>
  <add ... />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Hmm, instead I just made the default web app (primary app) a web application also. Now I have an empty website directory with 2 webapps inside of it. Do you know how I can make the main website url www.mydomain.com go to App1 by default without doing (www.mydomain.com/App1/?

Comment: You can put a default page in your root website that does a Response.Redirect to the App1 subfolder.

Comment: Lets say I do that. How can I make it so when App1 is running it isn't using the folder name in the url and uses the primary domain. i.e. www.myapp.com/Page.aspx.... Then App2 will work as normal www.myapp.com/App2/Page.aspx. Because right now it seems that I am forced to use www.myapp.com/App1/Page.aspx.. I don't want the App1 part.

Comment: You could achieve that using URL rewriting: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.  Though maybe it's overkill: why not just sort out the web.config files?

Comment: Sorting out the web.config files seems to be the route I am going to take. I have everything working for the most part. I really appreciate your help. Thanks!